# Using characters such as ) in Bluemix runtime environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I've got a ruby on rails app running on Bluemix. With this app I use a couple of services, one of which is Object Storage.

Logically, I want to put the credentials that I use for each environment (dev and prod) in the environment variables that you can specify in the runtime tab within Bluemix.

I want to put a password like this in there:

```
23aSeefae,,)ewFe
```

The runtime environment is not accepting the ) sign.

It says:
[image]

I have tried double quotes, single quotes and I have tried to escape the ) sign with a backslash.

Any help would be appreciated. Is there any way in which I can store my variables outside of my app and within the Bluemix environment instead?

PS: password is not a real password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten help from the Bluemix support as well now. This is by far most easy way to do what I want:

You can set environment variables through the Cloud Foundry command line interface.

```
cf set-env <APP_NAME> <ENV_VAR_NAME> <ENV_VAR_VALUE>
```

You will have to restage your app before you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind (connect) your Object Service instance to your application in Bluemix so the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable is automatically created for you.

Here is an example of a VCAP_SERVICES env variable for an application binding Object Storage service instance (I have modified some data for security reasons):

```
{
    "Object-Storage": [
        {
            "credentials": {
                "auth_url": "https://identity.open.softlayer.com",
                "project": "object_storage_a92583b3_329e_4ed8_8918_xxx",
                "projectId": "7f1f5659d21340dfaa4568dxxxx",
                "region": "dallas",
                "userId": "abcdefghxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "username": "admin_3ff9bf1e187e7fa02e28c96232dxxxxxxx",
                "password": "BF_0_)s3#xxxXXbY^",
                "domainId": "79fc08601744486abf930000000000",
                "domainName": "761111",
                "role": "admin"
            },
            "syslog_drain_url": null,
            "label": "Object-Storage",
            "provider": null,
            "plan": "standard",
            "name": "app-object-storage",
            "tags": [
                "storage",
                "ibm_release",
                "ibm_created"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can then read this as JSON object in  your ruby code, for example:

```
vcap_services = JSON.parse(ENV['VCAP_SERVICES'])
credentials = vcap_services["Object-Storage"][0]["credentials"]
password = credentials["password"]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, you're right, I have connected my service already and I also see my VCAP_SERVICES, I also have this listed. However, I have to request and list credentials seperately for actually writing to containers with for example Fog, right? Via the service credentials tab? If not: how do I access the password that is listed in the VCAP_SERVICES? ENV['password']?

Comment: This was the easiest way to solve my problem, thanks! However, if you need to access an environment variable that is not already there in VCAP_SERVICES, you could also create your own service with the 'cf cups' command. It stands for "create user provided service" and can be found here https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html. In this service you can fill any type of credential which is thereafter to be bound to the app with a connection. Then the service details can be used to access via VCAP_SERVICES as Alex has explained.